# ¿Qué tiene de "pan" el oro?

Tags: etimología

Mi hija me ha preguntado por qué se le llama "pan" al pan de oro. Vamos: que qué tiene que ver.

Primero he pensado "esto está *chupao*, lo busco en un momento" y después "pues va a ser que no". Y ahora "pues una buena pregunta para SSE".

Por lo visto, [*pan*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RcmAvfa)(6) es una "hoja muy fina, de oro, plata u otros metales, que sirve para dorar o platear" (no tiene que ser de oro necesariamente).

En el DLE la única etimología que se nos da es que viene del latín *panis*, pero no explica qué tenía en la cabeza el primero que usó esta palabra para una lámina fina de metal. O tal vez haya alguna etimología omitida que no es la de los otros "panes" del DLE.

¿Alguien sabe qué tiene de *pan* el *pan de oro*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es bastante probable que el uso de *pan* como "lámina fina" provenga del procedimiento de cocción de las hostias. Ya en el Diccionario de Autoridades de 1737 las definiciones de *pan* incluyen (una junto a otra) la de "hoja de harina... que sirve para hostias" y la de "hoja muy delicada... de oro, plata u otros metales".

[image: pan]

Nótese que las traducciones latinas de ambas definiciones referencian el término *bractea*, que en latín se usaba como "hoja fina de metal" (es decir, nuestro actual "pan [de oro, plata, etc.])" y también a veces como "lámina de madera fina usada como revestimiento". Que pudiera traducirse "hostia, lámina fina de pan" como *bractea panis* dice mucho de las connotaciones del término.

Por alguna razón dejamos de usar *bractea* con ese significado (hoy *[bráctea](https://dle.rae.es/?id=61hfxul)* es un término técnico de la botánica), pero parece que *pan* quedó asociado a la idea de "lámina".

Comment: Un siglo antes del _Autoridades_, Covarrubias decía en su diccionario de 1611 que "por imitacion a forma dezimos pan de higos, de açucar, de rosas, de xabon, y panes de oro, y panecillos de sal". En el CORDE he visto usos de "pan de oro" hasta en el siglo XV, siendo el texto más antiguo anterior al año 1429.

Comment: A falta de más información, me quedo con esta explicación, que parece que lleva la dirección adecuada. Aun así, plantea puntos enigmáticos: por un lado, la palabra común en ambas definiciones es _bractea_, no _panis_ y , como tú dices, "por alguna razón", _bractea_ desapareció. El estudio de tal proceso en los textos debería ser de interés para los expertos y lo que me extraña es que, siendo la técnica y la palabra tan antiguas, los etimólogos no se hayan ocupado de esclarecer la evolución en el uso del término. Tendría que haber rastros de tal discusión entre los académicos.

Comment: Plinio el Viejo, en el capítulo XXXIII de su Historia Natural trata de esta técnica. Sería interesante tener acceso al texto latino para examinar qué términos usa. Este uso de "pan" para el oro solo lo he encontrado en español y catalán (seguramente aparece en uno por influencia del otro).

Answer (score 0):

> "esto está chupao, lo busco en un momento"

And you are very right.

[Se denomina pan de oro a una lámina de muy poco grosor elaborada con oro batido. Se obtiene mediante el martillado de grandes planchas de oro, o aplicando presión a éstas a través de un conjunto de **rodillos**<sup>1</sup>.](//www.kaosystem.com/blog/rotulacion-mano/que-es-el-pan-de-oro-y-para-que-se-utiliza.html)

---

A *rodillo de laminar*:

[image: rodillo de laminar]

---

A *rodillo de amasar*, universal symbol of bakery, it's a very similar device:

[image: rodillo de amasar]

---

A *pan amasao* is a possible product:

[image: pan amasao]

Also *obleas de pan*, *tortas de aceite*, *empanadas*, *pasteles*...

---

<sub>1: Emphasis mine.</sub>

Comment: 'Rodillos' can be used only in a very early step in the long and laborious gold leaf production. I don't know exactly how it's made nowadays in factories, but even in the XX century was handmade by beating. By rolling, you get sheets, that are much thicker: gold leafs are seven times thinner than rolling paper and translucent. I don't think Romans had rolls hard and precise enough.